# Setting up multi webcam streaming

Tags: html, ffmpeg, streaming, webcam, ffserver

we are currently planning to connect all our offices via webcams selectable from a website. So I guess the setup could be something like this:

```
Webcam 1 \
Webcam 2 - > Streamserver -> Webserver displaying html5 Video 
Webcam n /
```

I've made first tests from streaming from Windows using VLC to a central ffserver, but the results where rather bad (after 1-2 frames the stream stopped).

Do you have any suggestions on 
- which stream software I can use on the client/webcam site (Linux or Windows)
- which software I can use on the server side (Linux) for collecting and recoding streams?

Thanks,

Moritz

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend using WebRTC instead of VLC & ffserver.

All you will need for this implementation is a central node server.

And if you did not want to go the webRTC rout you could always just stream right over a socket, but I really think webRTC is the way to go.

from scratch :
http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/webrtc/basics/

using something made to make it a little simpler :
http://simplewebrtc.com/